# Какую формулу для Excel использовать для сокращения названия продукта?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

У меня есть список товаров, их около 500 штук. Я хочу предоставить эти товары через API.

Например, для получения информации о шоколаде mars используется такой запрос: https://127.0.0.1/goods?key=mars. В ответ клиент получает некоторую информацию: сколько на складе, сумма и т.д...

Кроме марса есть и другие у которых имена очень длинные например "Домик в деревне", "Оливия Польша", "Оливия Венгрия".

Есть ли в Excel формула, которая сокращает название так, чтобы оно оставалось понятным?

Вот отличный пример:

[image: пример]

Comment: Биржевые тикеры в приведенном скриншоте генерятся не автоматически, а по опр. правилам ([как?](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/09/translating-ticker-talk.asp)) – скорее всего, вручную.

Comment: С этим да 100% согласен. У них то оборотов столько) Мне бы только чтобы с одного было понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вряд ли кто-то будет запоминать, держать в голове, что «ОВен» – это «Оливия Венгрия».

У тех, кто запрашивает, скорее всего, будет прайс-лист, или другой список продуктов. Пусть это будет **словарь**: две колонки, одна полное название продукта, вторая – короткий код.

Код этот может быть как просто числами `1, 2, 3,...` так и, скажем, с префиксами: «М» – Молóчка, «К» – кондитерские, и т.п. Итого `М1009` - «Оливия Венгрия», и запрос  `https://127.0.0.1/goods?key=M1009`.

Только не меняйте эти индексы со временем, а то, мало ли, у кого-то *словарь* старый на руках.

**Альтернатива** – делать **поиск**: простой, продвинутый – как сможете. Тогда ваш прайс будет как Яндекс: `https://127.0.0.1/goods?q=Оливия` и в выдаче будут все товары, где в названии есть слово "Оливия".

---

**Upd.** Если хотите именно сокращать, то я бы [транслитерировал](http://sirexcel.ru/makrosi_vba/kak-transliterirovat-tekst-v-excel-russkij-tekst-preobrazovat-v-anglijskij-translit/) и убирал все гласные, кроме первой в каджом слове, пробелы, и менял регистр: первая в каждом слове заглавная, остальные строчные:

```
"Оливия Венгрия" - "OlvVngr"
```

Надо обязательно проделать тест на повторы, прогнав весь список ассортимента через сокращалку. Обратная расшифровка невозможна, поэтому при запросе подробностей, надо весь список товаров прогонять через формулу (или таки добавить колонку), и искать в ней присланный в запросе "хэш".

Comment: Эти короткие имена будут встречаться не только в запросе. Пока я подсчитал 5 местах будет. Я решил отказаться от цифровых ID, так как в прошлый раз постоянна была запарка с ними :(  Так что мне в любом случае нужно что то придумать чтобы сокращать их и переводить на латиницу :)

Comment: Любое сокращение чревато коллизиями – когда два разных названия дадут одно короткое имя.

Кто ещё, и как, будет тоже пытаться переводить названия в короткие в других 4-х местах? Везде будет ваш Excel, или где-то человек, где-то другая платформа?

Comment: пока думаем насчет этого. Скорее всего Excel. При импорте в базу данных товары проходят проверку человеком. Товаров то ведь на самом деле не очень много. Их не 10000, а примерно 1000 может 2000

Comment: В результате что вот такое получилось https://jsfiddle.net/e52864pm/ 

Вроде то что надо :)

Comment: Молодцы. А как же регистр букв? Чтобы не `HLB-BRDNSKY`, а `HlbBrdnsk` – на 2 символа короче (ещё и без гласных в конце).

Comment: Пока рабочую версию сделал, вроде работает, но все же нуждается в доработке. Сейчас работаю с моделями данных, и тут появляются еще дополнения. Как только с данными закончу буду модифицировать код